# Is it possible to turn a Minecraft single player map into multi-player server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got some funky minecraft maps that I'd like to share with my friends. However, they're, more often than not, far away and unable to stop by my computer and see what I've wrought.

I was wondering if there was a way to transform a singleplayer map into a multiplayer one, such that I could share my singleplayer creations remotely?

Comment: All minecraft maps are capable of supporting multiple players now, so this question has been rendered obsolete.

Comment: Isn't deleting this a bit excessive if someone's caught on a (very) old version? Just update the question to be "in versions earlier than ___..."

Comment: I just googled for exactly this problem, since I was experimenting with older versions. Then I saw it was "too localized". I would suggest reopening this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, just copy the world you want to share to minecraft server directory, delete old world named "world", and rename the directory of your single player world to "world".
You can insert single player world into SMP.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to rename it to world - you can just change the name from world in the "server.properties" file.

Comment: @soulBit I just told the easier method, and yes, i know you can change server.properties, but for beginners, it could be really confusing.

Comment: Hey, what's SMP?

Comment: @tobych Survival MultiPlayer, probably a legacy abbreviation by now.

Comment: Copying is a good suggestion, but isn't a perfect solution. I would like to sync changes betweeen the two, or better still, share a single save for use by both single player and server-based games.

Answer (score 6):

Alright, here we go. Go to "run" and type `"%appdata%"`. After that, click on the  ".minecraft" folder. Look in there for a folder named "saves". Open that up and leave that there. Next, go to "Minecraft.net", press download, and then click on and download "Minecraft Server.exe", which should be 270 kilobytes big. Alternatively, you could use "Minecraft Server.jar", which is smaller. Once you are done with that, copy the world that you want to convert (from the "saves" folder) and paste it in the server folder. Now delete the folder called "world", and then rename your map folder's name to "world". Then go to "Mincraft_Server". It will take some time to load, but will get there.

Comment: Hello, Kidspinach, and welcome to gaming! I've edited out the question from your answer; If you'd like to ask a question of your own, please do so in a separate thread via the ASK QUESTION button on the top right. Be sure to check our [FAQ] if you have further questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can always just e-mail them the map if you want them to see and play on it, but that will of course only allows them to play it in single player. If you want to be able to play it with them, you'll need to set up a server, like Riki137's answer states.

Comment: Your friends must have a large inbox! The world I have right now is 165MB.

Comment: Dropbox! (is your friend)