# Can i invite someone to my single player world? If so, How?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to turn a Minecraft single player map into multi-player server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-minecraft-single-player-map-into-multi-player-server)

I have wanted to invite my brother to my Single Player world because he hasn't been able to find much diamond. I can find 30 in an hour so I wanted to give him some diamond, build a house for him and have him help me in my mine, but I don't know if I can. I don't want to play on a multiplayer server because it's very time consuming to make one and I don't want to get griefed on a public one.

How can we play together?

Comment: -1 this question is not clear, and there isn't any way to do this aside from a server.

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to get another person to play in the world with em. Moving it to a server Is the answer, and is possible.. So I am not sure how this is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a local multiplayer server that uses your single player world as the world.
Basically, what you do is copy the files in your single player folder over for the server to use. There's a little bit of set up needed. Here's a walkthrough:

Answer (score 1):

A multiplayer server is the **only way** for two players to exist in the same world.

Even if you set up a server for your world, however, neither you nor your brother will be able to bring items into or out of that world, as your character's inventory is not shared between worlds/servers.

It sounds as if you may be familiar with Terraria's world/character system, which allows characters to switch between worlds at will and worlds to be opened in single- or multiplayer mode.  Minecraft doesn't follow the same model; the closest you can get would be to spawn some diamonds in your brother's world (via mod or inventory editor) and destroy the same number in yours (say, by tossing them into lava).

Comment: Actually, with some clever file renaming, you *can* carry over inventories.  (But they come packaged with all other data about the player like location.)

Comment: @John — It's possible to get single-player inventories into multiplayer this way, but it requires copying the single-player files from each computer, possibly editing player position so as not to spawn embedded in a mountain, and those files can't be easily converted back to single-player afterward because the world data is discarded.  Again, it's possible to get around this using NBT editors, but it's hardly worth the effort simply to trade items.

Comment: True, it *is* a pain in the neck, but not impossible, like you make it sound.

Answer (score 0):

It's not time consuming to make a server, all you have to do is download the server file from Minecraft's website ([link](http://www.minecraft.net/download)), run it in a folder where you the server files, and your done. To have people connect to it give them your IP, and enable port forwarding for port 25565.

Another explanation can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server).

Comment: I think you missed the part where he doesn't want to start his world over again :)

Comment: He doesn't. Just delete the `world` folder in the server and drag in your world.