# How do I make a server out of a map I've already made?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to turn a Minecraft single player map into multi-player server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-minecraft-single-player-map-into-multi-player-server)

I want to start up a server, and I want to do so out of a map I've made. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, chase, and welcome to gaming! This question has been answered pretty rigorously over here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-minecraft-single-player-map-into-multi-player-server

Comment: And also this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19780/how-can-i-host-my-own-minecraft-server