# How do I move a Minecraft saved world from my desktop to my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been working a lot on my world on my computer in single player mode. My dad got me a server and so I want to transfer my world onto my server.  How is this possible?

I noticed that in `%appdata%\roaming\.minecraft\saves`, the directories in there look a lot like the world directory on my server. Can I simply transfer my saves directory to my server?

Comment: Hi Ken, and welcome to Arqade! I think your question's already been answered; please see the responses to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-minecraft-single-player-map-into-multi-player-server).

Comment: Yep, drag and drop and you're ready to go.

Comment: Is this a server that you bought or a server that is running off of a computer you have access to?

Comment: @JeffreyLin - my dad rented me a server at baremetalcloud.com. Thanks others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there are saves in `%appdata%\roaming\.minecraft\saves` that you can use. All you need to do is drop it into the server folder after you create it and specify in the server config file (`World_Name=`) and write the name of you world.

In newer versions within the `server.properties` file the variable is now called `level-name` instead of `World_Name`.

Comment: place all your on-character items in a chest before you save it and transfer, when you log into the server you might start as a fresh character

Comment: Any way to move the character-related things too?

Answer (score -1):

Drag the folder of the world into your server folder then --->

you can just set the Level-name: (Name of folder in servers main folder)

If your default world is named world but you want to change it to a world called world2

You just drag the world2's world folder into the server folder and switch

Level-name: world to Level-name world2

This will be in the config file in your server folder