# Can you move previous world data into a Minecraft Realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After multiple at home servers crashing, I'm trying to decide if purchasing a realm would be worth it.

My only question is if you can move pre existing worlds into a new realm? So say I purchase a realm for 13/month, could I upload the world we're using now onto it?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I move a Minecraft saved world from my desktop to my server?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93903/how-do-i-move-a-minecraft-saved-world-from-my-desktop-to-my-server)

Comment: @ChaseC, I knew this was possible, but I am not sure if we have the same privileges with Moajang Relams?

Comment: @ChaseC Realms has a whole different set of tools than regular servers if I understand correctly. It launched with a minimal subset of the server management tools you had with a full server.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Yamikuronue.  Realms is a different beast from running a server on a headless machine in your house or on a VPS provider.

Comment: [Not yet](https://minecraft.net/realms/faq)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MrLemon is correct as of Minecraft 1.7.9. However, Minecraft 1.7.10 came out literally today, June 26; Searge tweeted that it was released between MrLemon's answer being posted and mine being posted. It includes the following changes for Realms:

> **World uploader** – upload your local world to Realms (finally!)
>
> Command blocks! (finally!)
>
> Player activity monitor – when and for how long a player has been
>   online (see who plays when you sleep!)
>
> Access to more server settings (yey!)
>
> Improvements in Realms UI (also yey!)

--[Source](https://mojang.com/2014/06/minecraft-1-7-10-on-thursday/?utm_source=feedly&utm_reader=feedly&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=minecraft-1-7-10-on-thursday) (emphasis mine)

So yes, you can. Happy Realms-uploading day!

Comment: Talk about a weird happenstance