# trying to copy a single player minecraft world onto a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

First off, i'm using a mac laptop. That might be the issue right there but I don't have another computer to use. Im trying to copy the world using the "minehut" tutorials but they haven't been working. Can anyone walk me through what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move a Minecraft saved world from my desktop to my server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93903/how-do-i-move-a-minecraft-saved-world-from-my-desktop-to-my-server)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find your single player world file and copy it into your server folder. Then, edit the server.properties file in a text editor. Find the property called "world-name" and change the text to the right of the = sign to your new world file name.