# can you lock a map in minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

im trying to get a map from a singleplayer world into a multiplayer server, is it possible to lock a map in minecraft 1.12.2 and bring it to a server using saved toolbars? this is the item map, not the actual minecraft world.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I move a Minecraft saved world from my desktop to my server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93903/how-do-i-move-a-minecraft-saved-world-from-my-desktop-to-my-server) (the bit about locking the world appears to be part of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/566903))

Comment: not the WORLD, a MAP.

Comment: Yes, I did make that mistake. Duplicate flag retracted.

Comment: I'm not sure how a map retains its data when copying it using MCedit (e.g. drop it in a chest, and copy&paste that chest onto the server). But It'll probably lose the data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Minecraft 1.12.2, it is not possible to lock a map nor is it possible to transfer it to another server. If you put a map in the saved toolbar and use it on another server it will not retain its data.

Comment: It's possible to transfer the area that was responsible for creating the map (say, using chained structure blocks), then rebuild it at the destination, and generate the map from that.

Comment: i am sad... can you transfer a locked map to a 1.12.2 server using a map from another update?